# How to use style property in Typescript

Tags: javascript, ionic3

I want a slideshow in simple html and javascript. i have written my code below. there is an error in using style property to hide and show image. I used this code in typescript (ionic). I have error in both lines having style property in code  'x[i].style.display'. Please tell me how to use style

Html code is -

```
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_mountains.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        French Alps
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-display-container mySlides">
      <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_forest.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <div class="w3-display-bottomright w3-large w3-container w3-padding-16 w3-black">
        Northern Lights
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button class="w3-button w3-display-left w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
<button class="w3-button w3-display-right w3-black" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>
```

Typescript code-

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController)
{
    var slideIndex = 1;
        showDivs(slideIndex);

        function plusDivs(n) {
          showDivs(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function showDivs(n) {
          var i;
          var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
          console.log(x);
          if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
          if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
           for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
             x[i].style.display = "none";  
           }
           x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Which line of your code throws an error?

Comment: Do you accept JQuery?

Comment: error is in -> x[i].style.display

Answer (score 0):

You calling your scripts before page loaded.
Remove showDivs(slideIndex) call from script and call it in onload:

```
<body onload="showDivs(1)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTMLDivElement in TypeScript. For example;

```
var container: HTMLDivElement;
container.style.color = "red";
```